# Get the count of the number of documents in a Collection Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to list all the collection names and the document count for each collection in a single query?

The one that I could find only gives the count for a particular collection.
For example, if `Users` was a collection then

```
db.Users.count()
```

Would give me the count of the number of documents in the collection `Users`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the shell all you need to do is this:

```js
db.getCollectionNames().map(function(name) { 
    return { "name": name, "count": db[name].count() } 
})
```

There is no "command" and there is not "singular" collection query ( it is technically still multiple queries made for each collection, and a "source" query ) to do this since that is not how MongoDB stores the data. But there is a simple programitic method, and this is basically available to all drivers as well.

Comment: so the query would be `db.getCollectionNames.map()` ?

Comment: @Vaulstein the `db.getCollectionNames()` is a function in itself, that performs a system command to return "collection info". The result is an array of conditions suitable to the `.map()` operator in JavaScript. As you should "see clearly" here. `.count()` is run for every collection that is returned. This is "just how it works". As I said, the same command to return "collection info" is available in every driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print the numbers and count, then you can use forEach.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(colName){
  print(colName+": "+db.collection(colName).count());
});
```

If you want to use it for any other operations, then you can use map function.

```
db.getCollectionNames().map(function(colName){
  return {
    "columnName":colName,
    "count":db.getCollection(colName).count()
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't. You have to use

```js
var collections = db.runCommand({
  listCollections:1,
  filter:{ name:{ $not: /^system\..*/ } }
})
```

to get all collections created by the user and iterate over those collections

```js
for (var index = 0; index < collections.length; index++) {
    var current = collections[index];
    var doccount = db.runCommand({collStats:current,scale:1024,verbose:true}).count;
    print(current + ":" + doccount);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Just curious. All other solutions include `system.indexes`, and using `map` effectively does shoot multiple queries, too.